# Calling a method gives different result

Tags: php

I want to collect some data from a 3rd party page. I use http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ for this. In the construct I get the select item from the page and I pass it to the `loopSelect($html)`, which loops through the options (some product category), and whit the new parameter (product category) it makes a POST call to the page. The server returns a string (the select box of the subcategories).

**The problem:**

The line `var_dump($select);` returns empty string. If I remove the line `$type = $this->getBetween...` it works as expected, I can see the select's string with each subcategory for each product category.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param array $search
 * @return string
 */
function getSelect(array $search = [])
{        
    $default = [
        'option' => 'com_batteryfinder',
        'format' => 'raw',
        'controller' => 'batteryfinder',
        'task' => 'getdropdown',
    ];

    $data = array_merge($default, $search);
    var_dump($data);
    // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data),
        ),
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    return file_get_contents($this->url, false, $context);               
}


function loopSelect($html)
{
    $name = $html->find('select',0)->getAttribute ( 'name' );
    foreach($html->find('option') as $option)
    {
        if ($option->value)
        {
            $this->formData[$name] = $option->value;

            $select = $this->getSelect($this->formData);

            var_dump($select);

            $type = $this->getBetween($select, "loadSearchSelect(options, '", "');");

        }
    }         
}
```

Looks like calling a method `getBetween` messes up everything.

```
function getBetween($out, $start, $end)
{
    if (strpos($out, $start) === false)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }        
    $startsAt = strpos($out, $start) + strlen($start);


    $endsAt = strpos($out, $end, $startsAt);
    if ($endsAt=== FALSE)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    return substr($out, $startsAt, $endsAt - $startsAt);        
}
```

### EDIT

passing `$select` into a new variable seems to solve the problem, but I don't get it why?

```
        $this->formData[$name] = $option->value;

        $select = $this->getSelect($this->formData);

        var_dump($select);

        $out = $select;

        $type = $this->getBetween($out, "loadSearchSelect(options, '", "');");
        var_dump($type);
```

Comment: Despite looking somewhat awkward to me with the mismatched false and FALSE, your function ``getBetween()`` seems to be performing as intended when I test it myself.  [https://3v4l.org/NSP6f](https://3v4l.org/NSP6f)  I don't think your problem is in that function.

Comment: @spynix yes it does what it should. But if I don't remove it var_dump($select) gives an empty string. Weird.

Comment: @spynix see my edit...

Comment: My best guess at that is var_dump is failing due to the html string.  Try wrapping your select variable before dumping it and see if that solves it.

Comment: @spynix what do you mean by "due to the html string". How should I "wrap" $select? Please elaborate further.

Comment: A simple example of wrapping would be to echo <pre></pre> around your dump.  Try something like this: ``echo "<pre>"; var_dump(htmlspecialchars($select, ENT_QUOTES)); echo "</pre>";`` and see if that yields something more useful.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with $select. If you read again my question I get it back as expected, only if I add $this->getBetween... The $select from getSelect is the same in both case. And see my solution (EDIT). Why does   passing into a new variable solve it?

Comment: Ah, I was still thinking your dump was failing.  What version of PHP?

Comment: @spynix PHP version 5.4.3

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm about to be too obviuos, but, have you got display errors active? May getBetween be causing some error that is not being displayed and finishes the execution of the script? Or var_dump  is showing a 'String(0) ""' or like, and the script finishes ok.

Anyway, why aren't you using regular expressions to implement getBetween function?